# 160 character message counter shows NaN at starting

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to count characters of a message and if the number of characters crosses 160, I am incrementing the number of messages, but the problem is before I start typing the Total SMS(s) shows NaN, once i start typing it works perfect.

Second problem is, I want to increment the sms cost as the number of messages increases, please see the code below.

```
<textarea class="text-input--underbar" placeholder="Enter Message" style="width: 100%; height: 100px;" onkeyup="textCounter(this,'counter',160);" ng-model="message" name="message" id="message" required></textarea>

Remaining Characters : <input disabled  maxlength="3" size="3" value="160" id="counter"> / SMS

Total SMS(s) : {{ (message.length - message.length % 160) / 160 + 1 }}

Cost : {{sms_rate}}&cent / SMS
```

Please see the screenshot below.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest writing a method on the controller to handle your mathematics. The reason you get NaN is because at the start 'message' is blank, thus the length is 0. And I'm sure you know, 0 divided by anything gives errors.

So for example your method:

```
function calcTotal() {
  var total = (message.length - message.length % 160) / 160 + 1;
  return Number.isInteger(total) > 0 ? total : 0;
}
```

And in your template:

```
Total SMS(s) : {{ calcTotal() }}
```

You have a safety net by checking if total is a number. If it isn't, return 0 so you don't get 'NaN'.

As for your incrementation. You can have some kind of counter in your controller to keep track of how many messages have been sent, which you can then use to change the cost of SMS.

Comment: when do i call this `calcTotal()` function? on key up?

Comment: No, you can put it into your template as is. Angular will constantly update the controller-template link (the $digest loop). If you change something in the message, the total will be calculated 'on-the-fly' for you.

Comment: @rrd Is that a JS/Angular -Thing? If I divide 0/160 I get 0 on my calculator. If I divide 160/0, that is obviously wrong as you can't divide by 0.